# Call Flask functions inside templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on my website with Flask and Jinja templates, and I have an odd bug about including images in templates. I have a `post.html` template that inherits from a `base.html`, and it gets passed a post object from an SQL database. The problem is that some of the Jinja templating functions don't get called when I do so, namely image HTML tags don't load correctly based on the `url_for()` call. Regular HTML tags are fine, as I use `|safe` to make they get processed.

Example from the `post.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="post-description">
        <p>
            {{post.body|safe}}       
        </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Example from that `post.body` call:

```
<b> I work, and am bolded</b>
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/randomImg.png') }}">
```

While the bold text shows up fine, the `url_for` is never called. In the outputted source (on the actual website), it's easy to verify, as the src link is never properly represented, unlike other pages where the function is evaluated. If I copy/paste the `<img>` line so that now my `post.html` looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="post-description">
        <p>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/randomImg.png') }}">
            {{post.body|safe}}       
        </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The first image call loads fine, but the one's inside post.body do not. I'm not sure if there's a Flask or Jinja way to force it to evaluate it, but I'm hoping so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post.body` was not processed the way you want it, because jinja2 does not try to rerender its own output by default, which makes perfect sense.

You could render the post body and then render response:

```
@app.route("/some/path")
def some_view():
    # ...
    post = Post.query.first()
    rendered_post_body = render_template_string(post.body)
    return render_template("some_template.html", post_body=rendered_post_body)
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, but I was unable to get the function called still. I quickly just made a "blank.html" file which only contains `{{ data | safe}}`. I then "double called" render_template on it: `render_template('blank.html', data=render_template('blank.html', data=post.body))` with no change unfortunately

Comment: You mean that `rendered_post_body` did not contain evaluated `url_for`? If so, could you print `post.body` and `rendered_post_body` inside **view** and provide the output?

Comment: You need [`render_template_string`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.render_template_string) not `render_template` for creating the `rendered_post_body`.  Remember, the first argument to `render_template` is supposed to be the path to the template.